# implementation of sha-256 in perl

Tags: perl, padding, sha

i'm trying very hard on implementing the sha-256 algorithm. I have got problems with the padding of the message. for sha-256 you have to append one bit at the end of the message, which I have reached so far with `$message .= (chr 0x80);`
The next step should be to fill the emtpy space(512bit block) with 0's.
I calculated it with this formula: l+1+k=448-l and append it then to the message.
My problem comes now:Append in the last 64bit block the binary representation of the length of the message and fill the rest with 0's again. Since perl handles their data types by themself, there is no "byte" datatype. How can I figure out which value I should append?

please see also the official specification:
http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-3/fips180-3_final.pdf

Comment: Why not just use `Digest::SHA` / `Digest::SHA::PurePerl` ?

Comment: I'm doing it for educational purposes

Comment: Almost everybody would do it as 32-bit integer. I have yet to see a library (in c or perl) do it byte by byte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If at all possible, pull something off the shelf. You do not want to roll your own SHA-256 implementation because to get official blessing, you would have to have it certified.

That said, the specification is

> #### 5.1.1 SHA-1, SHA-224 and SHA-256
>
> Suppose that the length of the message, *M*, is *l* bits. Append the bit `1` to the end of the message, followed by *k* zero bits, where *k* is the smallest, non-negative solution to the equation
>
> *l* + 1 + *k* ≡ 448 mod 512
>
> Then append the 64-bit block that is equal to the number *l* expressed using a binary representation. For example, the (8-bit ASCII) message “**abc**” has length 8 × 3 = 24, so the message is padded with a one bit, then 448 - (24 + 1) = 423 zero bits, and then the message length, to become the 512-bit padded message
>
> ```
>                                   423       64
>                                  .-^-.  .---^---.
> 01100001  01100010  01100011  1  00…00  00…011000
>    “a”       “b”       “c”                  '-v-'
>                                              l=24
> ```
>
> Then length of the padded message should now be a multiple of 512 bits.

You might be tempted to use [`vec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/vec.html) because it allows you to address single bits, but you would have to work around funky addressing.

> If bits is 4 or less, the string is broken into bytes, then the bits of each byte are broken into 8/*BITS* groups. Bits of a byte are numbered in a little-endian-ish way, as in `0x01`, `0x02`, `0x04`, `0x08`, `0x10`, `0x20`, `0x40`, `0x80`. For example, breaking the single input byte `chr(0x36)` into two groups gives a list `(0x6, 0x3)`; breaking it into 4 groups gives `(0x2, 0x1, 0x3, 0x0)`.

Instead, a [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) template of `B*` specifies

> A bit string (descending bit order inside each byte).

and `N`

> An unsigned long (32-bit) in "network" (big-endian) order.

The latter is useful for assembling the message length. Although `pack` has a `Q` parameter for quad, the result is in the native order.

Start with a bit of prep work

```
our($UPPER32BITS,$LOWER32BITS);
BEGIN {
  use Config;
  die "$0: $^X not configured for 64-bit ints"
    unless $Config{use64bitint};

  # create non-portable 64-bit masks as constants
  no warnings "portable";
  *UPPER32BITS = \0xffff_ffff_0000_0000;
  *LOWER32BITS = \0x0000_0000_ffff_ffff;
}
```

Then you can defined `pad_message` as

```
sub pad_message {
  use bytes;

  my($msg) = @_;
  my $l = bytes::length($msg) * 8;
  my $extra = $l % 512;  # pad to 512-bit boundary
  my $k = 448 - ($extra + 1);

  # append 1 bit followed by $k zero bits
  $msg .= pack "B*", 1 . 0 x $k;

  # add big-endian length
  $msg .= pack "NN", (($l & $UPPER32BITS) >> 32), ($l & $LOWER32BITS);

  die "$0: bad length: ", bytes::length $msg
    if (bytes::length($msg) * 8) % 512;

  $msg;
}
```

Say the code prints the padded message with

```
my $padded = pad_message "abc";

# break into multiple lines for readability
for (unpack("H*", $padded) =~ /(.{64})/g) {
  print $_, "\n";
}
```

Then the output is

```
6162638000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018
```

which matches the specification.

Comment: after editing your code to mine, it seems to work! very good explanation, thank you. i would like to publish "my" work afterwards as cc. would you be ok with that? here is the github link github.com/napcae/sha256_perl

Edit: I have to revise my comment. I commented out 
`die "$0: $^X not configured for 64-bit ints"
    unless $Config{use64bitint};`

and printed the message with 
`print unpack("H*", $message);`
But that gives me something like 616263800000...001800000018

Comment: @TrungNguyenChi The code above is a gift. Feel free to include it in your repository. I strongly advise *against* commenting out the `use64bitint` check because the code will fail silently on platforms that don't support 64-bit `int`. Silent failures are the worst kind. I'm curious: what motivated you to comment out that capability test?

Comment: because the code worked only with 64bit versions of perl, thank you. I'll keep you up to date

Answer (score 5):

First of all I hope you do this just as an exercise -- there is a `Digest` module in core that already computes SHA-256 just fine.

Note that `$message .= (chr 0x80);` appends one byte, not one bit. If you really need bitwise manipulation, take a look at the `vec` function.

To get the binary representation of an intger, you should use [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html). To get it to 64 bit, do something like

```
$message .= pack 'Q', length($message)
```

Note that the 'Q' format is only available on 64 bit perls; if yours isn't one, simply concatenate four 0-bytes with a 32 bit value (pack format `L`).

Comment: I still get the ascii representation of 1, altough I'm concateate `$message .= 0b1;`. I don't understand how to use vec, there aren't very good tutorials either :/